# bash script to parse csv files according to their names

Tags: bash, csv

I have multiple csv files with the names

```
   VAR1_VAR2_VAR3_VAR4.csv
```

All the files have the same structure inside just values change.
I am trying to retrieve data from those files by fixing at each time one or more VAR. 
I tried to write a script but I have 2 problems:

1- since all files have the same structure, so I know exactly all field, I want to retrieve the data according to the row and column number (i.e, $(R1,C4)). Is't possible to do this?

2- When I fix one variable (i.e, *_VAR2_VAR3_VAR4.csv ) on when VAR1 have 3 entries how to iterate this variable inside a loop ?

My script is here (My first tentative)

```
  #!/bin/bash          
  #OLDFIS=$IFS
  #IFS=","
  awk -F "," '
  #-------------------------- Table 1  ----------------------- -------#
  BEGIN {

  print"=========================================================="

  printf"%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s\n","Network size", "P_Energy", "E_Energy",      
 "All_energy","Latency"

  print"=========================================================="
  }



 {printf  "%-8d %-8d %-8d %-8d %-8d\n",$VAR1, $(R3,C3) ,$(R4,C4) ,$(R5,C5),$(R6,C6)   
  ,$(R7,C7)}' /home/jhon/Desktop/Simulator/results/*_VAR2_VAR3_VAR4.csv 

  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

In this example I want to fix VAR1, which will be the first column in my output.The others filed I know their cordinates in the files.

EDIT 1:

For my first question I change the code to:
   NR==3 {printf "%-20s", $1 } NR==25 {printf "%-20s", $2 }   NR==12 {printf "%-20s", $2 }
   NR==29 {printf "%-20s", $2 } NR==49 {printf "%-20s", $4 }' /...PATH/simStats_P-
   Mesh__random_16384_1E-4_16.csv >test.txt
I get the desirable output:

```
 ===================================================================================
Network size       P_Energy           E_Energy           All_energy         Latency             
=====================================================================================
                0.0402597           0.00767312          0.0479328           0.294311
```

EDIT 2:
I get all values now by using FNR instead of FN

For the first row I put fake value. Any idea how to add a loop to parse files according to their names?

Comment: For the first point, yes, you can "play" with `NR` (number of record, in this case number of line) and the column number. So to get `R1, C4` you can do `awk 'NR==1 {print $4} file`.

Comment: @fedorqui `$4`, instead of `$C4`.

Comment: @Bernhard errr yes, solved :)

Comment: thnks, when I write like this "{printf  "%-8d %-8d\n", NR==15 $2 , NR==25 $2}' /home/achraf/Desktop/Simulator/results_SEP30_P_mesh_256cores/simStats_P-Mesh__random_16384_1E-4_8.csv >test.txt" I get always zero!

Comment: @user1425371 it is not like that how you use `NR`. Note that `awk` reads the file sequentially, so you cannot access to different lines at the same moment. You need to store the value and then print it in the `END{}`.

Comment: @fedorqui Can you please tell me where I put the END block

Comment: @user1425371 you can do it like `awk 'NR==1 {myvar=$4} END {print "the value was", myvar}' file`

Comment: @fedorqui. Thanks, I used FNR instead of NR and I could get all values for for the specified files

Answer (score 0):

I used split with awk and I put manually the number of the parameter that I want to show in the first column.

```
 awk -F "," '
 FNR==1 {nb_param=split(FILENAME,param,"[_.]"); printf "%5s", param[7] }  
 FNR==25 {printf "%20s", $2 } 
 FNR==12 {printf "%20s", $2 } 
 FNR==29 {printf "%20s", $2 } 
 FNR==49 {printf "%20s\n\n", $4 }' *.csv
```